# Mybatis insert freezes when done in a task

Tags: spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have an sql session thus defined:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="BATCH" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="..." />
</bean>

<bean id="taskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
</bean>
```

Now, in my service, I have to make some select on a table and some inserts in a **different** table.

```
@Transactional
public class MyWebService{
   @Autowired
   private TaskExecutor executor;
   @Autowired
   private SelectTableMapper sm;
   @Autowired
   private InsertTableMapper it;

   public void service(){
     int rowCount = ...//getting row count
     int batch = rowCount/numThreads;
     //computing an interval for each thread with non overlapping rows
     for(int i=0;i<numThread;i++)
        executor.execute(new MyTask(//interval//));

     ..waiting for all tasks and finally returning
   }

   private class MyTask implements Runnable{

         public void run(){
              List<Row> rows = sm.select(//interval//);
              for(Row row : rows){
                   if(//some condition//)
                       it.insert(row); //if I comment here it successfully completes

              }

         }

   }

}
```

Problem is that program just freezes! And I am sure it is not my logic's fault because program successfully ends by commenting the insertion line.
So I guess it is a concurrency problem on the second table, the one I am inserting data in.

Comment: It hard to say without seeing `InsertTableMapper.insert` statement. You can diagnose this problem by making several stacktrace dumps in a row (via jstack/jconsole/jvisualmv) when the program freezes. If stacktrace show you that program really freezed on call to database then you need database level tools to see what lock the freezed query tries to get and what other transaction is holding them. This depends on the database (in postgresql you should use pg_stat_activity and pg_locks to do that).